# What is the best solution to pass two different parameters to a REST API?

Tags: rest, api, web-services, restful-url

I have a doubt about what could be the best way to define a REST URI for an API.

I have an API that provide the details of a commodity.

So I know that I can do a **GET** request like this:

```
http://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.TTT:8280/commodity_details/1
```

where **commodity_details** is what I want to obtain (a commodity details) and **1** is the ID of a specific commodity. This should be a proper REST URI.

Ok, I know that I can also pass the ID parameter into a JSON document doint a **POST** request like this:

```
http://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.TTT:8280/commodity_details/
```

and attacching a JSON payload like this to my **POST** request:

```
{
"commodity_id": 1
}
```

I think that if I have the single **commodity_id** parameter maybe is better the first version (putting the required ID into the URI), is it?

But what happens if I need a second **language_id** parameter? (my API should receive also this **language_id** parameters so it can provide an internazionalized output in the proper language.

So in this case I need to pass 2 parameters (**commodity_id** and **language_id**).

In this case is better use a **POST** request with a JSON payload that contains both the parameters? Something like this:

```
{
"commodity_id": 1,
"language_id": 2
}
```

Or what could be a good URI template for this scenario?

Comment: Don't roll your own - [`Accept-Language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language). Generally, for cross-cutting concerns that you still want in the URL, you could use [the query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) - `/commodity_details/1?language=2`

Comment: the parameters with é is not orrible implementing RESTful API? 
And what about the Accept-Language? Is it an header that can be setted to select the desidered langunage?

Comment: 1. ...what? 2. I provided link to MDN, did you read it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For passing just 2 parameters you can go with first approach(query string parameter) which is simpler to use

```
[HttpGet("{commodity_id}/{language_id}")]

public string GetCommodityDetails(string commodity_id, string language_id)  
{  
string commodityDetails=string.empty;

//your implementation

 return commodityDetails;  
}
```